# Are webhooks a thing only on Wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress, webhooks

I am really angry when reading Wordpress documentation sometimes. There is page about webhooks [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/webhooks/) but in my installation that option is missing. I even switch to english version of admin panel to check but nothing.
So is webhooks only feature of wordpress.com or can be use elsewhere on self-hosted WP installation?
Why the documentation is not clear about this?

There must be some internal hooks somewhere otherwise how the RSS Feed would be generated after publishing new post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the page you linked to isn't Wordpress documentation, it's a support article on the use of Wordpress.com hosted sites.

Wordpress has a number of [action/hook functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category:Actions), however external notifications aren't a standard feature, so you'll need a plugin to do this on self-hosted Wordpress, such as [PubSubHubbub](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pubsubhubbub/) (the only one I can find which still appears to be maintained) or [HookPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hookpress/).

Answer (score 0):

I use [WP Webhooks Pro](https://ironikus.com/downloads/wp-webhooks-pro/) for some time now if it comes to webhooks.

Except for the fact that WordPress doesn't support webhooks by default, there are two more things you should think about when it comes to WordPress and webhooks:

1. Sending data
2. Receiving data

If you want to send data, then HookPress was for a long time the main solution (It doesn't support the newest PHP versions yet). At the moment I use two different plugins for that: 1. EDD Zapier (For sending my orders to Zapier) and 2. WP Webhooks Pro (To send user information to Zapier)

For receiving data, I used for a long time only Zapier, but the possibilities there are very limited since you can't, for example, create users. In this case, I fully switched to WP Webhooks Pro.

For very special use cases, you should check if there are integrations available that focus exactly on that. For RSS Feeds, I would also suggest [PubSubHubbub](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pubsubhubbub/)